# VBA button create new sheet from template

Tags: vba, excel, templates

I'm new to Excel so I hope this makes sense. 
In the code below, I have a user form that contains a button, and once clicked it creates a new sheet and renames the sheet corresponding to the text fields that were filled out on the form. I have a template sheet in my workbook and I was wondering if there are any ways to have the newly created sheets from the user form to follow the same template. I also understand that this is the code to create an exact replica of a sheet:

```
Dim i as byte
for i=1 to 5
Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy after:=sheets("TEMPLATE")
Next I
```

But I don't know how or if its possible to fit it in with my code:

```
If Me.cbStores.Value = "Northern / Northmart" Then
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets.Add
sh.Name = AddEmployeeUF.txtFirstname.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtMiddleinitial.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtLastname.Text + "Template"
ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), Address:="", SubAddress:=sh.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="View"
End If
```

Anything helps! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sheets.Copy method unfortunately doesn't return a reference to the new created sheet. However, you can access it easily as activeSheet.

```
Dim i as byte, sh as worksheet
for i=1 to 5
    Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy after:=sheets("TEMPLATE")
    set sh = activeSheet
    ' Do whatever you have to do with the new sheet
    sh.Name = AddEmployeeUF.txtFirstname.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtMiddleinitial.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtLastname.Text + "Template"
    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), Address:="", SubAddress:=sh.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="View"
Next I
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. Is there anyway to do this but have the sheet created in a different workbook?

Comment: If you make the "After:=" property in the Copy method refer to a sheet in another workbook, it will copy to that workbook (this would require that you have a reference to the workbook are trying to copy the sheet to). Also if you are trying to create a new workbook for each copy, the default behavior of the .Copy method is to create a new workbook if you do not specify a "Before" or "After" property.

Comment: @Wedge will the Copy method create one in a separate workbook as well as the current one? Because I only want it to create it in the separate workbook, not the current one.

Comment: Copy called with no parameters only creates a copy in a new workbook. It will create a new workbook every time you do it though. If you want to compile all the sheets in a single new workbook, you would want to create a new workbook and then copy the sheets into that workbook.